# Testing useSubscription apollo hooks with react

Tags: react-hooks, apollo, subscription, apollo-client, apollo-server

Testing the `useSubscription` hook I'm finding a bit difficult, since the method is omitted/not documented on the [Apollo docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/development-testing/testing/#testing-mutation-components) (at time of writing). Presumably, it should be mocked using the `<MockedProvider />` from `@apollo/react-testing`, much like the mutations are in the examples given in that link.

Testing the loading state for a subscription I have working:

**Component:**

```
const GET_RUNNING_DATA_SUBSCRIPTION = gql`
  subscription OnLastPowerUpdate {
    onLastPowerUpdate {
      result1,
      result2,
    }
  }
`;

const Dashboard: React.FC<RouteComponentProps & Props> = props => {
  const userHasProduct = !!props.user.serialNumber;

  const [startGetRunningData] = useMutation(START_GET_RUNNING_DATA);

  const [stopGetRunningData] = useMutation(STOP_GET_RUNNING_DATA);

  useEffect(() => {
    startGetRunningData({
      variables: { serialNumber: props.user.serialNumber },
    });

    return () => {
      stopGetRunningData();
    };
  }, [startGetRunningData, stopGetRunningData, props]);

  const SubscriptionData = (): any => {
    const { data, loading } = useSubscription(GET_RUNNING_DATA_SUBSCRIPTION);

    if (loading) {
      return <Heading>Data loading...</Heading>;
    }

    const metrics = [];
    if (data) {
      console.log('DATA NEVER CALLED IN TEST!');
    }

    return metrics;
  };

  if (!userHasProduct) {
    return <Redirect to="/enter-serial" />;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <PageContainer size="midi">
        <Panel>
          <SubscriptionData />
        </Panel>
      </PageContainer>
    </>
  );
};
```

And a successful test of the loading state for the subscription:

```
import React from 'react';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { createMemoryHistory } from 'history';
import { create } from 'react-test-renderer';
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import wait from 'waait';
import { MockedProvider } from '@apollo/react-testing';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';

import Dashboard from './Dashboard';

import {
  START_GET_RUNNING_DATA,
  STOP_GET_RUNNING_DATA,
  GET_RUNNING_DATA_SUBSCRIPTION,
} from './queries';

const mockStore = configureMockStore([thunk]);

const serialNumber = 'AL3286wefnnsf';

describe('Dashboard page', () => {
  let store: any;

  const fakeHistory = createMemoryHistory();

  const mocks = [
    {
      request: {
        query: START_GET_RUNNING_DATA,
        variables: {
          serialNumber,
        },
      },
      result: {
        data: {
          startFetchingRunningData: {
            startedFetch: true,
          },
        },
      },
    },
    {
      request: {
        query: GET_RUNNING_DATA_SUBSCRIPTION,
      },
      result: {
        data: {
          onLastPowerUpdate: {
            result1: 'string',
            result2: 'string'
          },
        },
      },
    },
    {
      request: {
        query: STOP_GET_RUNNING_DATA,
      },
      result: {
        data: {
          startFetchingRunningData: {
            startedFetch: false,
          },
        },
      },
    },
  ];

  afterEach(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });

  describe('when initialising', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      store = mockStore({
        user: {
          serialNumber,
          token: 'some.token.yeah',
          hydrated: true,
        },
      });
      store.dispatch = jest.fn();
    });

    it('should show a loading state', async () => {
      const component = create(
        <Provider store={store}>
          <MockedProvider mocks={mocks} addTypename={false}>
            <Router history={fakeHistory}>
              <Dashboard />
            </Router>
          </MockedProvider>
        </Provider>,
      );

      expect(component.root.findAllByType(Heading)[0].props.children).toBe(
        'Data loading...',
      );
    });
  });
});
```

Adding another test to wait until the data has been resolved from the mocks passed in, as per the instructions on the last example [from the docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/development-testing/testing/#testing-mutation-components) for testing useMutation, you have to wait for it.

**Broken test:**

```
it('should run the data', async () => {
      const component = create(
        <Provider store={store}>
          <MockedProvider mocks={mocks} addTypename={false}>
            <Router history={fakeHistory}>
              <Dashboard />
            </Router>
          </MockedProvider>
        </Provider>,
      );
      await wait(0);
    });
```

**Error the broken test throws:**

```
No more mocked responses for the query: subscription OnLastPowerUpdate {
```

**Dependencies:**

```
    "@apollo/react-common": "^3.1.3",
    "@apollo/react-hooks": "^3.1.3",
    "@apollo/react-testing": "^3.1.3",
```

**Things I've tried already:**

- react-test-renderer / enzyme / @testing-library/react
- [awaiting next tick](https://github.com/trojanowski/react-apollo-hooks-sample-test/blob/master/src/__tests__/Hello-test.js)
- [initialising the client](https://github.com/trojanowski/react-apollo-hooks-sample-test/blob/master/src/__tests__/Hello-test.js#L31-L36) in the test differently

**Github repo with example:**

https://github.com/harrylincoln/apollo-subs-testing-issue

Anyone out there able to help?

Comment: Can you add the code of `GET_RUNNING_DATA_SUBSCRIPTION` subscription ?

Comment: @Fraction Done! Thank you!

Comment: that doesn't help much, can you share a repo with a sample code to reproduce your issue ?

Comment: @Fraction - https://github.com/harrylincoln/apollo-subs-testing-issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I can see here is that you're declaring the `SubscriptionData` component inside the `Dashboard` component so the next time the `Dashboard` component is re-rendered, the `SubscriptionData` component will be re-created and you'll see the error message:

> No more mocked responses for the query: subscription OnLastPowerUpdate

I suggest that you take the `SubscriptionData` component out of the `Dashboard` component so it will be created only once

```
const SubscriptionData = (): any => {
  const { data, loading } = useSubscription(GET_RUNNING_DATA_SUBSCRIPTION);

  if (loading) {
    return <Heading>Data loading...</Heading>;
  }

  const metrics = [];
  if (data) {
    console.log('DATA NEVER CALLED IN TEST!');
  }

  return metrics;
};

const Dashboard: React.FC<RouteComponentProps & Props> = props => {
  const userHasProduct = !!props.user.serialNumber;

  const [startGetRunningData] = useMutation(START_GET_RUNNING_DATA);

  const [stopGetRunningData] = useMutation(STOP_GET_RUNNING_DATA);

  useEffect(() => {
    startGetRunningData({
      variables: { serialNumber: props.user.serialNumber },
    });

    return () => {
      stopGetRunningData();
    };
  }, [startGetRunningData, stopGetRunningData, props]);

  if (!userHasProduct) {
    return <Redirect to="/enter-serial" />;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <PageContainer size="midi">
        <Panel>
          <SubscriptionData />
        </Panel>
      </PageContainer>
    </>
  );
};
```

And for the tests you can try something like this:

```
let component;
it('should show a loading state', async () => {
      component = create(
        <Provider store={store}>
          <MockedProvider mocks={mocks} addTypename={false}>
            <Router history={fakeHistory}>
              <Dashboard />
            </Router>
          </MockedProvider>
        </Provider>,
      );
      expect(component.root.findAllByType(Heading)[0].props.children).toBe(
        'Data loading...',
      );

      await wait(0);
});

it('should run the data', async () => {
      expect(
        // another test here
        component.root...
      ).toBe();
});
```

Comment: That's done it, @Fraction. Moving `<SubscriptionData />` out into its own component made all the difference - I have such tired eyes! Thanks again